# Controllers subdirectory is not accessibile

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a small test project with this structure:

```
\controllers
  - admin
    -- migration.php
welcome.php
```

When I try to access http://myprojectname/admin/migration I receive a 404 error.
Off course if I try to access welcome/index, all works fine.

Seems like the controller does not follow the correct route.

Any hint? I'm following a tutorial, I did not write any fancy code!

Answer (score 0):

first check you have removed index.php from url or not  or try using this link

http://myprojectname/index.php/admin/migration

and also there should be an index function in your migration.php file which leads you to a view file.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this url checked it That's working.

```
http://myprojectname/admin/migration/functionname
```

you can also fixed in route section like this 
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/migration/$1';